# Getting result of Python commands in script editor, Maya 2015

Tags: python, maya

Is there any way to view the result of the commands you are running in Maya with Python, without adding extra print statements, like they do in this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXFGeZZbMzQ#t=217

I'm  quite sure there was no need for this in earlier versions of Maya...

Answer (score 0):

Single statements will print their values without prints:

```
33 + 44
```

will print

```
77
```

without extra work.  Same is true for functions:

```
cmds.ls(type='transform')
```

in an empty scene will print out

```
['top', 'left', 'front', 'persp']
```

However you **don't** get this behavior if you execute **more than one line at a time.**